# Special character parsing issue with php and html

Tags: php, html

I am getting issue with special character parsing in php and html. Label name called 'Tell us what you’re looking' showing 'Tell us what you�re looking for' In to browser.

Comment: plz share PHP Code

Comment: Try using a proper apostrophe character rather than a "smart quotes" character.... they're called "smart" but they're really pretty stupid

Comment: Here is code - `code`<label><?php echo ("Tell us what you’re looking for (i.e. full-time / part-time team member)") ?></label><br />`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solutions. here is code :

```
<label><?php echo utf8_encode("Tell us what you&rsquo;re looking for (i.e. full-time / part-time team member)") ?></label>
```